# Fetch a specific field of a pdf from a mail with power automate

Tags: power-automate

I'm currently doing some work that can easily be automated.

On a specific frequency (each week) I receive a mail (always from the same person) with the same object (at the end he adds the week number), this mail contains a pdf file and I need to fetch one specific number which is contained in an array in this pdf.

Once I have this number I need to create an email and put this number in an array and send it.

In my opinion, this can be easyli automated but I don't know how to specifically fetch a specific value in a pdf file, in my example I always have a sentence like "This is the number of events:" and then the number

I'm not sure about which operation choose from in power automate.

Comment: You wanna use PA desktop or cloud for this?

Comment: Cloud would be more convenient